# How to 'check for elements', 'click button', 'check elements have increased by one'? - .then() event order isn't clear

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I am trying to achieve what I laid out in the title. Here is my code.

```
    //Add item button found previously

    cy.get('#container').then(($container) => {
      const beforeLength = $container.children.length;
      if ( beforeLength === 0) {
        addItemButton.click();
        cy.get('.item').should('have.length', 1);
      } else {
        //We actually enter the else condition
        addBlockButton.click();
        cy.get('.item').should('have.length', beforeLength + 1);
      }
    })
```

`The error I get is Expected <div.item> to have a length of 3, but got 1`

Basically, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to extract the `beforeLength` so I can compare it to the `afterLength`, particularly in scenarios where before length might be 0.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which way you were aiming to go, but `$container` is a jQuery object, so to obtain it's children you need the [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method.

Or, in [native javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) the `.children` property could be used but you would have to extract the native element with `$container[0]`.

```js
    cy.get('#container').then(($container) => {

      const beforeLength = $container.children().length;

      // or

      const beforeLength = $container[0].children.length

      if ( beforeLength === 0) {
        addItemButton.click();
        cy.get('.item').should('have.length', 1);
      } else {
        addBlockButton.click();
        cy.get('.item').should('have.length', beforeLength + 1);
      }
    })
```

I can't resolve to the problem `The error I get is Expected <div.item> to have a length of 3, but got 1` as I can't see any HTML.

It seems like `beforeLength` must be 2 since the error **expected to have length of 3** equates to the `beforeLength + 1` expression, which would mean the else branch was active.

This is a perfect illustration of why you need to set up the test pre-conditions first, i.e set up `0` items in one test and `> 0` items in another test, and therefore avoid using `if - else` constructs. The way you have it, the test will only have 50% coverage any way it goes - not adequate in my opinion.